# AttributeError using mrcnn package in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use Masked RCNN in Python through mrcnn package but I'm getting errors.

I'm using Keras 2.0.8 and Tensorflow 1.13.1 But, no luck so far.

Here's the code I've written

```
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils
from mrcnn import visualize
```

While trying to import the above, I'm facing this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Which version of keras are you using?

Comment: Please post the full error message as *text*, *not* screenshot; plus, the code you show is not identical to the one shown in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the versions of the libraries:

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
```

If `tensorflow, keras, h5py` are not

```
tensorflow==1.13.1
keras==2.0.8
h5py==2.10.0
```

do this. This worked for me to solve this issue:

```
pip uninstall keras -y
pip uninstall keras-nightly -y
pip uninstall keras-Preprocessing -y
pip uninstall keras-vis -y
pip uninstall tensorflow -y
pip uninstall h5py -y
```

Then reinstall keras and tensorflow:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
pip install keras==2.0.8
pip install h5py==2.10.0
```

Remember that if you are on jupyter notebook, then

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
!pip install keras==2.0.8
!pip install h5py==2.10.0
```